# Is the verb "to see" a metaphor?

Tags: grammar, verbs, semantics, metaphors, be

For example, when one thinks an argument is invalid, one can say "I see this argument as invalid".
Nevertheless, I always thought a metaphor requires, at minimum, requires two object/ideas; that is, a transfer of qualities from one object/idea to another object/idea. As in the metaphor "John is my sunshine," the qualities of sunshine are transferred to the subject "John".
However the verb "to see", taken alone, does not appear to be a metaphor.

Comment: A simplistic view of metaphor looks at a simple structure. _John is a tiger._ Tenor  (real entity referenced) = John (really, John himself rather than a proper noun in a sentence). Vehicle = tiger. But a simple extension shows that the simile form, 'John is like a tiger' has precisely the same tenor and vehicle, and intended point/s of comparison. Similes are a certain written form of metaphors.  With 'I see he is angry', 'see' is obviously used figuratively (especially if spoken by a blind person). This is the broad metaphor 'mental perception' = 'seeing',  with 'appear',...

Comment: 'come to light', 'dawn on someone', a lightbulb moment', 'enlightenment' ... various expressions exemplifying this metaphor.

Comment: _See_ is not itself a metaphor, but it's a big part of the metaphor theme `Seeing Is Knowing` that allows you to see the problems with an argument, even though you can't see how somebody could make it. Almost all metaphors are projections of the human body, and sense verbs are prominent. Read Lakoff and Johnson.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'm not sure that _metaphor_ is the right category for it, so neither 'yes' nor 'no' to your question. It's closer to a _broadening_ of the verb's meaning, though there is some picture language involved.

Comment: There is the germ of a decent idea here..just needs some judicious editing and some research...

Comment: It is difficult to answer a question about classifying something in the abstract, without knowing the purpose of the classification. What hinges on whether we say that it is, or that it isn't, a metaphor?

Comment: You are seeing with your mind, not your eyes to mean understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *see* is a metaphor in *I see this argument as invalid*. It’s  metaphorical because it’s being used figuratively. *Percieve* would be a literal word to use there.

Here’s what the *OED* has to say:

> Because the sense of sight affords far more complete and definite
> information respecting external objects than any of the other senses,
> mental perceptions are in English (as in many other languages) often
> referred to in terms of visual perception, and vice versa, often with
> little or no consciousness of metaphor.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com)
> (login required)</sub>

Here’s that quote in context:

> **see**, *v.*
> **II.** To perceive or apprehend with the mind.
>  <sub>Because the sense of sight affords far more complete and definite information
> respecting external objects than any of the other senses, mental
> perceptions are in English (as in many other languages) often referred
> to in terms of visual perception, and vice versa, often with little or
> no consciousness of metaphor. Cf. INSIGHT *n.<sup>1</sup>*, PERCEIVE
> *v.*, SUSPECT *v.*, VIEW *n.*, VISION *n.*, etc.</sub>
> **10.**
> **a.** To perceive or apprehend with the mind; to understand or come to understand (the truth, the answer to a question, the purpose of
> something, etc.); to recognize or be aware of (a situation, problem,
> etc.).
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com)
> (login required)</sub>